# Draft.js: Change color of caret

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, draftjs

I am using Facebook's Draft.js library to create a rich text box and I have a requirement to make the caret of the text box red. Is it possible?

I have read about the `-webkit-text-fill-color` property but it is making the typed text and the placeholder red instead of the caret.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will make the caret red, and the text black, in webkit browsers:

```
.public-DraftEditor-content {  
  color: red;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Here's a fiddle showing it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/2atqzz5r/

**Update:** 
As of Chrome 57, you can use the new property [caret-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/caret-color):

```
.public-DraftEditor-content {  
  caret-color: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yuk0fogn/

Comment: I actually think it works in the latest version of Firefox. Here's a list of all browsers supporting it: http://caniuse.com/#search=text-fill-color

Answer (score 0):

Use caret-color:

```
div.class {
    caret-color : red;
}
```

[Supported in 56% of browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-caret-color)